# questdb： Table Busy is often displayed when data is inserting

Tags: questdb

Table Busy is often displayed when data is inserting.
The error message is:

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:

Error updating database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: table busy [reason=insert]
The error may involve com.secusoft.mapper.quest.CameraAccessDetailsMapper.insert-Inline
The error occurred while setting parameters
SQL: insert into camera_access_details_1_20211016 values (72, to_timestamp('2021-10-16 22:06:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),to_timestamp('2021-10-16 22:07:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 0, 0)
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: table busy [reason=insert]
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [00000]; error code [0]; ERROR: table busy [reason=insert]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: table busy [reason=insert]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Postgress connection protocol to insert data into QuestDB writing is forced to be single threading.
If multiple writes happen at the same time, `table busy` error is sent back to the client.

You can use REST api which will auto retry inserts or ILP which allow to insert from multiple connections simultaneously.